# Web Scrapping Python

Tags: python

Utilizava código abaixo para coleta de dados dos atms a partir dos parâmetros no terminal. Site foi alterado e não encontro o equivalente a isso para coleta dos dados.

Alguém saberia dizer se posso encontrar no inspecionar da página?

```
import requests

parametro = {'latitude':-23.5097042, 'longitude':-46.6717552, 'status':1, 'lista':1, 'limite':98, 'acessibilidade':''}

r = requests.get('https://www.banco24horas.com.br/index/busca-json-terminal',parametro)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando a janela de ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador aberta na aba de "rede" enquanto utilizamos o site buscando um caixa, vemos que a requisição mudou pra URL `"https://www.banco24horas.com.br/ajax.php"`.

Se tentarmos os mesmos parâmetros, porém, teremos um erro indefinido. Isso é porque os parâmetros mudaram, e agora, copiando da mesma requisição original que vimos, são os seguinte:

```
params = {'latitude': -23.5097042, 'longitude': -46.6717552, 'acess': 0}
```

Se fizermos a requisição nesse ponto teremos a seguinte mensagem:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH in <b>/var/www/html/b24h/ajax.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
{"type":"console","text":"No Ajax"}
```

Ela indica que algo mais é necessário pra que o sistema funcione: um header específico que também é enviado, o `X-Requested-With`. Se o incluirmos como segue, a requisição retorna os dados:

```
import requests

params = {'latitude': -23.5097042, 'longitude': -46.6717552, 'acess': 0}

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

r = requests.get("https://www.banco24horas.com.br/ajax.php", params=params, headers=headers)

print(r.json())
# {'Results': [{'id_atm': '47530', 'cd_atm': '47530', ...
```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro. Precisaria estudar JavaScript para conseguir dar suporte nesse tipo de leitura e análise?

Comment: Pra mim deu erro abaixo mas imagino que seja algo com proxy na empresa. Tentarei novamente no pc de casa. De qualquer forma, obrigado por esse apoio.


SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.banco24horas.com.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ajax.php?latitude=-23.5097042&longitude=-46.6717552&acess=0 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

Comment: @DiogoRibeiro não precisei usar javascript, só as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador, que aparecem quando se aperta F12. Quanto ao erro, sim, pode ser causado pelo proxy. Como parece ser erro de SSL, talvez resolva passar o argumento `verify=false` pro `requests.get`.